# Include \maketitle in table of contents to compile "book" of IEEE articles

Tags: table-of-contents, ieeetran

### Background:

I am creating a compilation of multiple IEEE format articles. This compilation will have a single table of contents. Each paper includes a title and `\maketitle` command. I would like the TOC to include the title of each paper as the primary level, along with all the sections/subsections etc.

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

    \begin{document}
    \onecolumn
    \tableofcontents
     \twocolumn        


    % Title and Author information  Paper 1
        \title{Title 1}
        \author{Author 1}
        % Make the title area
        \maketitle
       $ Paper Content

    % Title and Author information  Paper 2
        \title{Title 2}
        \author{Author 2}
        % Make the title area
        \maketitle
       $ Paper Content

\end{document}
```

Should generate a TOC that approximates this:

1. Title 1

   I - Section 1

   I-A Subsection 1

   I-B Subsection 2

   II - Section 2
2. Title 2

   I - Section 1

   I-A Subsection 1

   I-B Subsection 2

   II - Section 2

### Question:

How can I modify the TOC to include titles?

I am open to other suggestions. I realize that the ieeetran or other article/journal classes do not use `\chapter` or `\part` commands, but if there was a way to force this operation while not changing the class, I would be interested in such a solution as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please turn your example into a compilable one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\maketitle` is a command, which 'disables' itself right before the end of the macro (well, it is `\relax`ed then). As such, a further call to this macro will provide nothing. By using a patch command, this `\let\maketitle\relax` can be catched and a `\addcontentsline` command injected instead, which will do the ToC entry then.

I further introduced a `titlecounter` counter, which is automatically refstepped, so that `\label` should also work. The format of the ToC entry is quite simple at the moment -- change at will.

Mico had an important objection: There should be a `\clearpage` right at the start of the `\maketitle` command, which will shipout possible floats from the preceeding article. However, I restricted this behaviour to the 2nd etc. `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{titlecounter}
\xpretocmd{\maketitle}{\ifnumgreater{\value{titlecounter}}{1}}{\clearpage}{}{} % Well, this is lazy at the end ;-)

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\let\maketitle\relax\let\@maketitle\relax}{\refstepcounter{titlecounter}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect{\numberline{\thetitlecounter}{\@title~ \@author}}}}{\typeout{Patching was successful}}{\typeout{patching failed}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn        



% Title and Author information  Paper 1
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
% Make the title area
\maketitle
\blindtext[10]
%$ Paper Content

% Title and Author information  Paper 2
\title{Title 2}
\author{Author 2}
% Make the title area
\maketitle
\blindtext[20]
%$ Paper Content

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version with level indentation

Use `\setlength{\articlesectionindent}{10pt}` (or any other appropiate value), in order to get the indentation of levels relative to the title toc entry.

The resetting of sections etc. is done with the command `\@addtoreset{section}{titlecounter}`, i.e. each time the `titlecounter` is stepped, the sections are reset (and consecutively the subsections etc. as well)

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}%

\newlength{\articlesectionshift}%
\setlength{\articlesectionshift}{10pt}%
\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{\articlesectionshift}%

\makeatletter
\newcounter{titlecounter}
\xpretocmd{\maketitle}{\ifnumgreater{\value{titlecounter}}{1}}{\clearpage}{}{} % Well, this is lazy at the end ;-)
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\let\maketitle\relax\let\@maketitle\relax}{\refstepcounter{titlecounter}\begingroup
  \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{-\articlesectionshift}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect{\numberline{\thetitlecounter}{\@title~ \@author}}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}{\typeout{Patching was successful}}{\typeout{patching failed}}%

\@addtoreset{section}{titlecounter}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn        



% Title and Author information  Paper 1
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
% Make the title area
\maketitle

\section{First}
\subsection{First subsection of 1st section}%
\subsection{2nd subsection of 1st section}%
\subsection{3rd subsection of 1st section}%
\subsection{4th subsection of 1st section}%

\blindtext[10]
\section{Two}
\subsection{First subsection of 2nd section}%

% Title and Author information  Paper 2
\title{Title 2}
\author{Author 2}
% Make the title area
\maketitle
\section{First from second paper}
\subsection{First subsection of 2nd section of 2nd article}%

\blindtext[20]

%$ Paper Content

\end{document}
```

[image]

** Warning ** Both versions will fail in conjunction with `hyperref` package. It's some issue with the `\footnotemark` command.

Comment: Should you maybe also provide `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`) instructions just ahead of the `\maketitle` instructions?

Comment: @Mico: To get the correct pagenumbering?

Comment: I'm guessing that every article should start on a new page. However, I'll concede that the OP didn't actually say so.

Comment: @Mico: There are `\newpage` instructions in the `IEEEtran` version of `\maketitle`. But `\clearpage` would be better, perhaps, yes. Currently, each article starts with a new page

Comment: Thanks - I'd overlooked the fact that `\maketitle` (in its IEEEtran incarnation at least) implicitly generates a `\newpage`. Just in case the preceding article contains some accumulated floats that haven't been typeset by the time that article ends, it would be prudent to issue `\clearpage` explicitly, in order to "flush" those accumulated floats and not let them become intermixed with the next article's floats, right?

Comment: @Mico: That's true, of course, thank you for this idea! I think, there should be a `\clearpage` just before the 2nd `\maketitle`, because it's very unlikely, that there are floats between the `\tableofcontents` and the first article there?

Comment: You could also redefine `\maketitle` so that it executes `\clearpage` first, right?

Comment: @Mico: That was the stuff I had in mind ;-)

Comment: Got this implemented and working! Thank you! I still need some tweaking on this. I was envisioning two additional details: 1) that the numbering for sections and subsections, etc. for each paper would restart at each paper, and 2) that the section/subsection, etc headings in the TOC would be indented to indicate the level dependency on the titles.

Comment: Should I open another question for these modifications? Or is it fine to do that here?

Comment: @Dweeberkitty: Normally, it's a new question, but just wait a few minutes, perhaps I manage it rather quickly ;-)

Comment: @Dweeberkitty: Done ;-)

Comment: Perfect! This works great! Yes, I ran into the footnote problem too, but placing your code before hyperref is ever loaded fixed it.

Comment: @Dweeberkitty: Oh my, of course, `hyperref` should come last -- how could I forget.