# Turn off \appendices switch and resume normal section lables

Tags: sectioning, ieeetran

### Background:

I am appending several IEEE style papers using the solution [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203174/include-maketitle-in-table-of-contents-to-compile-book-of-ieee-articles)

Most of the papers include appendices using the `\appendices` switch to redefine `\thesection` to create Appendix A, B, C, etc. The problem I have is that \thesection is never redefined when a new paper is introduced to the document and hence what should be labeled Section 1 is now Appendix A.

### Question:

How do I redefine \thesection to resume normal section markings in the ieeetran style?

Comment: not having a real example to experiment with, i'm just making a wild guess.  the first thing i'd try is simply putting `\begingroup` before `\appendices` and `\endgroup` before `\end{document}` (or earlier, say before a bibliography, if that's appropriate).  if none of the changes made by `\appendices` are global, it should be sufficient to just "bury" them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I allowed myself to steal shamelessly the solution in  [Include \maketitle in table of contents to compile "book" of IEEE articles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203174/include-maketitle-in-table-of-contents-to-compile-book-of-ieee-articles) from that strange guy who provided it (;-))

`IEEEtran` is quite restrictive in the sense, that it does not allow `sections` after an `\appendix` or `\appendices` command. This way, it defines the macro

`\def\@IEEEdestroythesectionargument#1`

to issue a warning/error. It's possible to cure this, by insertion of the saved section macro `\let\LaTeXStandardSection` instead of the warning. (Small caveat: It won't work for section with optional argument however --> better way: patch the command out of `\appendix` etc.

The `\thesection` etc. counter format macros have to be restored at the end of `\maketitle`!

**Quick and dirty method** Redefine `\appendices` etc. such, that it does nothing else than resetting the counter format for the structuring level counters.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}%

\newlength{\articlesectionshift}%
\setlength{\articlesectionshift}{10pt}%
\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{\articlesectionshift}%

\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section
\let\LaTeXStandardTheSection\thesection
\let\LaTeXStandardTheSubSection\thesubsection
\let\LaTeXStandardTheSubSubSection\thesubsubsection
\let\LaTeXStandardTheParagraph\theparagraph


\makeatletter
\newcounter{titlecounter}

\xpretocmd{\maketitle}{\ifnumgreater{\value{titlecounter}}{1}}{\clearpage}{}{} % Well, this is lazy at the end ;-)
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\let\maketitle\relax\let\@maketitle\relax}{\refstepcounter{titlecounter}\begingroup
  \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\addtolength{\cftsecindent}{-\articlesectionshift}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect{\numberline{\thetitlecounter}{\@title~ \@author}}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
}{%
  \typeout{Patching was successful}
}{%
  \typeout{patching failed}
}%

\def\@IEEEdestroythesectionargument#1{\LaTeXStandardSection{#1}}%


\xapptocmd{\maketitle}{%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\LaTeXStandardTheSection}%
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\LaTeXStandardTheSubSection}%
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\LaTeXStandardTheSubSubSection}%
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\LaTeXStandardTheParagraph}%
}{}{}%


\@addtoreset{section}{titlecounter}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn        



% Title and Author information  Paper 1
\title{Title 1}
\author{Author 1}
% Make the title area
\maketitle

\section{First}
\subsection{First subsection of 1st section}%
\subsection{2nd subsection of 1st section}%
\subsection{3rd subsection of 1st section}%
\subsection{4th subsection of 1st section}%

\blindtext[10]
\section{Two}
\subsection{First subsection of 2nd section}%
\appendix
\section{First of Appendix}

% Title and Author information  Paper 2
\title{Title 2}
\author{Author 2}
% Make the title area
\maketitle
\section{First from second paper}
\subsection{First subsection of 2nd section of 2nd article}%

\blindtext[20]

%$ Paper Content

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! Testing this, more rigorously shows that multiple Appendices under "Paper 1" are now all labeled "Appendix A." I'm not sure how to modify the code to make this increment the Appendix counter correctly.

Comment: If you use multiple appendix sections, use `\appendices` instead of `\appendix`, however, this screws up the toc, adding `Appendix ` to each section title afterwards. This is weird. If you do not stick to this feature, it's best to redefine `\appendices` completely, to a very basic feature

Comment: I still have some problems with appendices as well as PDF bookmarks. But this answer is enough to get me on the right track. I'll perhaps post my solution when I get it all worked out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dweeberkitty: The problem with the bookmarks is inherent as the section counter is explictly reset, thus confusing `hyperref`. I have a way to get around this, it will probably solve all problems with your request, but give me some time, I have an important meeting tomorrow and you guess it, I have some trouble with time ;-)